# Python3: possible reasons for "No module named '<some.module>' " when trying to import `google.protobuf`?

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers, python-import

I am trying to build Google Protocol Buffers (`protobuf`) version 3.0.0-alpha2 (also tried 2.6.1) for Python3 and I have some difficulties.

On Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4.0 and 2.7.6 I built `protobuf` from source by running

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/../build-3.0.0
cd python
python3 ./setup.py build --cpp_implementation
# run build-3.0.0/bin/protoc to create *_pb2.py files
```

And I did the same with Python2 with two different results: on Python2 running

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./build-3.0.0/lib \
PYTHONPATH=./protobuf-git/python:./protobuf-git/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ \
python -c "import google.protobuf"
```

.. returns with no error. Trying the same with Python3 (and adapted path credentials of course) returns:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./build-3.0.0/lib \
PYTHONPATH=./protobuf-git/python:./protobuf-git/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/ \
python3 -c "import google.protobuf"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'google.protobuf'
```

I then compared both generated folders for python2.7 and python3.4 but they seem to be identical apart from some different file contents.

**So my question:** what can be the reason for `No module named 'google.protobuf'`? The specified folders exist in both cases so why does Python2 find `google.protobuf` and Python3 doesn't?

This is an excerpt of the file tree inside `protobuf-git`:

```
    protobuf-git
    |-- ...
    |-- python
    |   |-- README.md
    |   |-- build
    |   |   |-- lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    |   |   |   `-- google
    |   |   |       |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |       `-- protobuf
    |   |   |           |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |           |-- compiler
    |   |   |           |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |           |   `-- plugin_pb2.py
    |   |   |           |-- ...
    |   |   |-- lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    |   |   |   `-- google
    |   |   |       |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |       `-- protobuf
    |   |   |           |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |           |-- compiler
    |   |   |           |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |           |   `-- plugin_pb2.py
    |   |   |           |-- ...
    |   |-- google
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   `-- protobuf
    |   |       |-- __init__.py
    |   |       |-- compiler
    |   |       |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |       |   `-- plugin_pb2.py
    |   |       |-- ...
    |   |       |-- internal
    |   |       |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |       |   |-- ...
```

Comment: Are those spaces between `build` and `/lib` intentional?

Comment: they sneaked in when I tried to format this post - I'll correct it. Unfortunately this is not the reason.

Comment: I now know that it must be the environment in some way - when I'm running the very same commands from different Docker containers accessing the same folder on the host system I'm still getting different results.